# Loop doesn't perform function operations correctly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my nested loops to perform a check in / check out simulation. I have my functions set up and my loop at the end but it somehow always gives me the same output. Every patron has the same amount of books and a humongous fine instead of being totally randomized like the checkOut and isOverdue functions make them.

How do I make it so that the loops uses the randomly generated date from the functions and give each patron different amounts of fines and different books checked out? [Instructions for the project.](https://pastebin.com/tBuFRq3N)

My code:

```js
    var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
        this.title = title;
        this.Available = Available;
        this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
        this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
        this.callNumber = callNumber;
        this.Authors = Authors;
    };

    var Author = function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    };

    var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libCardNum, booksOut, fine) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.libCardNum = libCardNum;
        this.booksOut = booksOut;
        this.fine = fine;
    };

    function randInRange(start, end) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1)) + start;
    }

    Book.prototype.checkOut = function() {
        this.Available = false;
        var dateChk = new Date();
        var randDay = randInRange(1, 25);
        dateChk.setDate(dateChk.getDate() - randDay);
        this.checkoutDate = dateChk;
    };

    Book.prototype.checkIn = function() {
        this.Available = true;
    };

    Book.prototype.isOverdue = function() {
        var singleDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
        var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
        if (Math.round(difference / singleDay) >= 14) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    Patron.prototype.read = function(book) {
        this.booksOut.add(book);
    }

    Patron.prototype.return = function(book) {
        this.booksOut.remove(this.booksOut.length);
    }

    var authors = [];
    authors[0] = new Author("Auth", "One");
    authors[1] = new Author("AutL", "Two");

    var catalog = [];
    catalog[0] = new Book('Bk1', true, new Date(2001, 1, 21), new Date(), 123456, authors);
    catalog[1] = new Book('Bk2', true, new Date(2002, 2, 22), new Date(), 987656, authors);
    catalog[2] = new Book('Bk3', true, new Date(2003, 3, 23), new Date(), 092673, authors);
    catalog[3] = new Book('Bk4', true, new Date(2004, 4, 24), new Date(), 658342, authors);
    catalog[4] = new Book('Bk5', true, new Date(2005, 5, 25), new Date(), 345678, authors);

    var patrons = [];
    patrons[0] = new Patron('Pat1', 'Wat', 1, catalog, 0.00);
    patrons[1] = new Patron('Pat2', 'Wot', 1, catalog, 0.00);
    patrons[2] = new Patron('Pat3', 'Wit', 1, catalog, 0.00);
    patrons[3] = new Patron('Pat4', 'Wet', 1, catalog, 0.00);
    patrons[4] = new Patron('Pat5', 'Wut', 1, catalog, 0.00);

    //while loop or for loop for 90 days
      //For loop over catalog
         //forloop over patrons 
             //Check if available , if so check book out
             //If not available check book back in
                 //check checking back in check to see if book is overdue and if so add a fine
    //When down loop over patrons to see their fees

    for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < catalog.length; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < patrons.length; k++) {
                var fine = patrons[k].fine;
                if (catalog[k].Available) {
                    catalog[k].checkOut;
                } else {
                    catalog[k].checkIn;
                    patrons[k].read;
                }
                if (catalog[k].isOverdue) {
                    fine = fine + 5.00;
                }
                patrons[k].fine = fine;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < patrons.length; i++) {
        console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has checked out the following books:");
        for (j = 0; j < patrons[i].booksOut.length; j++) {
            console.log(patrons[i].booksOut[j].title);
        }
        console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has fine amount: $" + patrons[i].fine);
    }
```

Comment: please narrow down your question

Comment: hint: random number of books has no correlation to total length of any of the original arrays

Comment: @charlietfl Random number as in each patron has different books check out, not the number itself.

Comment: but that's not what you stated ... *"give each patron different amounts of fines and books"*

Comment: Search for "array shuffle" (lots of easy solutions on this site, easily found in google ) and use `Math.random()` to determine how much of the shuffled array to pass to each patron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a number of changes to your example so it actually works.

One very important thing to know is that when you call a method of an object you have to put parenthesis behind the call: not `catalog[j].checkOut` but `catalog[j].checkOut()`.

You can examine my changes and how the script works now. With this in hand you can formulate follow up questions.

Hope this helps.

```js
var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
        this.title = title;
        this.Available = Available;
        this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
        this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
        this.callNumber = callNumber;
        this.Authors = Authors;
    };

    var Author = function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    };

    var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libCardNum, booksOut, fine) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.libCardNum = libCardNum;
        this.booksOut = booksOut;
        this.fine = fine;
    };

    function randInRange(start, end) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1)) + start;
    }

    Book.prototype.checkOut = function() {
        this.Available = false;
        var dateChk = new Date();
        var randDay = randInRange(1, 25);
        dateChk.setDate(dateChk.getDate() - randDay);
        this.checkoutDate = dateChk;
    };

    Book.prototype.checkIn = function() {
        this.Available = true;
    };

    Book.prototype.isOverdue = function() {
        var singleDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
        var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
        if (Math.round(difference / singleDay) >= 14) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    
    // Changed the read method
    Patron.prototype.read = function(book) {
        this.booksOut[book.callNumber] = book;
    }

    // Changed the return method
    Patron.prototype.return = function(book) {
        delete(this.booksOut[book.callNumber]);
    }

    var authors = [];
    authors[0] = new Author("Auth", "One");
    authors[1] = new Author("AutL", "Two");

    var catalog = [];
    catalog[0] = new Book('Bk1', true, new Date(2001, 1, 21), new Date(), 123456, authors);
    catalog[1] = new Book('Bk2', true, new Date(2002, 2, 22), new Date(), 987656, authors);
    catalog[2] = new Book('Bk3', true, new Date(2003, 3, 23), new Date(), 092673, authors);
    catalog[3] = new Book('Bk4', true, new Date(2004, 4, 24), new Date(), 658342, authors);
    catalog[4] = new Book('Bk5', true, new Date(2005, 5, 25), new Date(), 345678, authors);

    // Changed how Patrons are initialised. Instead of passing the full
    // catalog for booksRead an empty object is passed.
    var patrons = [];
    patrons[0] = new Patron('Pat1', 'Wat', 1, {}, 0.00);
    patrons[1] = new Patron('Pat2', 'Wot', 1, {}, 0.00);
    patrons[2] = new Patron('Pat3', 'Wit', 1, {}, 0.00);
    patrons[3] = new Patron('Pat4', 'Wet', 1, {}, 0.00);
    patrons[4] = new Patron('Pat5', 'Wut', 1, {}, 0.00);

    //while loop or for loop for 90 days
      //For loop over catalog
         //forloop over patrons 
             //Check if available , if so check book out
             //If not available check book back in
                 //check checking back in check to see if book is overdue and if so add a fine
    //When down loop over patrons to see their fees

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // changed the for loop
        for (var j in catalog) {
            // changed the for loop
            for (var k in patrons) {
                var fine = patrons[k].fine;
                // Changed catalog[k] to catalog[j]
                // moved and changed patrons[k].read() call
                // added the patrons[k].return() call
                if (catalog[j].Available) { 
                    catalog[j].checkOut();
                    patrons[k].read(catalog[j]);
                } else if (patrons[k].booksOut[catalog[j].callNumber]) {
                    catalog[j].checkIn();
                    patrons[k].return(catalog[j]);
                }
                if (catalog[j].isOverdue()) {
                    fine = fine + 5.00;
                }
                patrons[k].fine = fine;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < patrons.length; i++) {
        console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has checked out the following books:");
        for (j in patrons[i].booksOut) {
            console.log(patrons[i].booksOut[j].title);
        }
        console.log(patrons[i].firstName + " has fine amount: $" + patrons[i].fine);
    }
```

**Edit**

Answer to the comment.

That is a result of how you set up your for loops. On the first day all the books go to the first patron, on the second day they go to the second partron and so on.

1. Day 1, book 1, patron 1: Book is available and goes to patron 1.
2. Day 1, book 1, patron 2: Book is not available.
3. ...
4. Day 1, book 2, patron 1: Book is available and goes to patron 1.
5. Day 1, book 2, patron 2: Book is not available.
6. ...
7. Day 2, book 1, patron 1: Book is not available, book is returned.
8. Day 2, book 1, patron 2: Book is available and goes to patron 2.
9. Day 2, book 1, patron 3: Book is not available.
10. ...
11. and so on

Comment: Why is it that the 3rd patron always ends up getting all the books?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions did not say to shuffle the books or patrons, during the simulation so your results would not be as random as your hoping for. Also looping over the books and patrons we can use a standard forEach vs a regular for loop making the code much easier to follow. I'm using lodash `_.shuffle` to randomize the books and patrons during each loop for better results. We can also hide the fine logic in our patrons return prototype ending up with a simple simulation.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
  _.shuffle(books).forEach(function(book) {
    _.shuffle(patrons).forEach(function(patron) {
      if (patron.hasBookCheckedOut(book)) {
        return patron.return(book);
      }

      if (book.available) {
        patron.read(book);
      }     
    });
  });
};
```

Working example http://jsbin.com/teyipak/1/edit?js,console